# Is the following sentence structure grammatical: S1 + V1, and Ving?

Tags: grammar

At first, when I was writing the intro for this IELTS question, it went:

*The line chart illustrates the proportion of New Zealand’s population growth in different age groups from 1950 to 2000 **and makes projections for the year 2050.***

But then I felt like it was too long a sentence, so I tried chunking it by adding a comma. However, I'm not sure if the following structure is grammatically correct:

*The line chart illustrates the proportion of New Zealand’s population growth in different age groups from 1950 to 2000,* ***and also making projections for the year 2050.***

Thank you so much in advance!

[image]

Comment: No, it;s incorrect. You need "and also **makes** ...".

Comment: So the following sentence must be incorrect too, isn't it? "The given line graph depicts the breakdown of the New Zealand population divided into 4 age groups starting in 1950, and including projections to the year 2050."

Comment: Yes, it's incorrect. The respective verb phrases are not parallel. You need "depicts ..." and "includes projections ...". **OR** "depicts ..., including" projections ...".

Answer (score 1):

> The line chart [illustrates the proportion of New Zealand’s population growth in different age groups from 1950 to 2000] and [makes projections for the year 2050].

> The line chart [*illustrates* the proportion ...] and [*makes* projections ...].

The phrases in brackets are parallel, and we need the present simple *makes* to maintain parallelism.

Adding the comma and *also* is fine, but the present simple *makes* is needed.

A different construction is possible if you must use the gerund-participle *making*:

> The line chart illustrates the proportion of New Zealand’s population growth in different age groups from 1950 to 2000, *making projections for the year 2050*.

Comment: +1 Yes, I agree!